# Favicon Does my site need to be hosted?

Tags: hosting, favicon

I was wondering If I need by website hosted to be able to use a favicon? At the minute my site is just a file thats I use expression web to edit with.

Comment: If the users can use favicon for their web pages, they will be happy for using favicon.  How do you think that web pages of stackoverflow use favicon?

Comment: The question is can I use a favicon without getting the website hosted?

Comment: Data of web file (HTML,text etc.) and data of favicon are came from web server. Web browser does not have function to show favicon from local file.  What do you want with favicon??? I cannot get it.

Comment: All I wanted to know is if I could use a favicon without the need to host as the site isn't finished. So you can't use a favicon until I get the site hosted on a web server?

Comment: Had you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server ? If not, read it for understanding web system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty old question but still...

Yes, your website MUST be hosted.
As a favicon is a file on the server (or somewhere outside of the server where your server fetches a file from), you need to have the website hosted for users to indirectly access the favicon and thus display it.
When your website ISN'T hosted it is NOT online thus users will not be able to read files from the server.

[image: Screebshot]

Here you see a screenshot of what I see when my website is NOT hosted.
You can see the favicon, because your webbrowser puts it in the cache (when you clean the cache it will not appear anymore).
Does this answer your question?

Comment: Ok, thanks I wondered why I couldn't view the favicon in the expression web viewer.